# Issue using jquery to display image previews on multiple file inputs

Tags: jquery, html, image-uploading

I am having trouble getting preview images to display on more than one file input field.

I have seen a number of posts here about it, tried out a few different thing but I cant seem to get my head around it.

I have added my code to jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5boja3mL/1/) so it can bee seen working.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="upload_main">
<div class="upload_label">
    <label>Main Photo</label>
</div>
<div class="upload_action">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="control" class="upload_one" style="display: none;" />
    <input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('control').click();" />
</div>
<div class="upload_placehold">
    <img id="blah" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div class="upload_clear">
    <a id="clear">Remove</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="upload_main">
<div class="upload_label">
    <label>Main Photo</label>
</div>
<div class="upload_action">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="control_one" class="upload_one" style="display: none;" />
    <input type="button" value="Browse..." onclick="document.getElementById('control_one').click();" />
</div>
<div class="upload_placehold">
    <img id="blah_one" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div class="upload_clear">
    <a id="clear_one">Remove</a>
</div>
</div>
```

**The jquery**

```
// Main Image
var control = $("#control");

$("#clear").on("click", function () {
    control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
});

$("#clear").click(function(){
    $('#blah').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/100x100');
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#control").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});


// Second Image
var control = $("#control_one");

$("#clear_one").on("click", function () {
    control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
});

$("#clear_one").click(function(){
    $('#blah_one').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/100x100');
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah_one').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#control_one").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

There is 2 inputs showing in the sample code, but there will be 7 file inputs.

Whats happening is, if I select an image using the first file input, its adding the preview to the last file input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working now, will post the solution as son as I get a few minutes.